# Prime Integer - Add Smallest Value - time limit exceeding python

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, primes

The program must accept N integers as the input. For each integer value X among the N integers, the program must print the smallest values that can be added to the integer X (possibly zero) so that the integer becomes a prime

```
Boundary :
1<=N<=2,00,000
2<=Each Int<=10^6
```

```
TimeLimit : 100 ms
```

My Code :

```
def isPrime(n) :
    if (n <= 1) :
        return False
    if (n <= 3) :
        return True
    if (n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0) :
        return False
    i = 5
    while(i * i <= n) :
        if (n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0) :
            return False
        i = i + 6
    return True
def summ(g):
    for i in range(20):
        if isPrime(g+i):
            return i
n = int(input())
print(*(summ(i) for i in list(map(int,input().split()))))
```

Example :

```
Input : 
7 
89 54 36 74 44 19 12
Output:
0 5 1 5 3 0 1
```

My code has no error, and i have used the `optimised` way to find whether a integer is prime or not but still i get time limit exceed for `N == 100,000` Is there any way to reduce the time limit to 100 ms

The worst case scenario is

```
n=200,000
[169988', '865748', '818394', '160754', '532538', '44700', '607214', '404390', '405894', '954978', '115734', '871022', '762398', '744128', '394638', '981440', '966030', '515540', '859578', '116240', '534858', '263984', '159408', '333930', '310728', '949262', '580734', '40032', '289244', '130052', '921200', '452534', '58632', '689964', '250920', '126224', '845184', '806088', '867734', '662370', '204668', '3728', '193164', '187964', '477260', '365138', '21194', '334760', '46272', '401244', '239934', '670490', '894330', '408770', '766068', '129968', '702828', '354464', '396834', '905340', '586770', '543860', '923388', '197610', '809834', '862344', '194204', '609278', '7874', '411158', '701220', '78780', '525980', '949812', '58700', '829224', '885608', '38630', '507372', '866330', '12918', '292058', '143978', '801290', '97460', '746118', '625610', '48590', '182124', '127952', '545388', '922638', '268050', '801488', '613290', '276278', '387138', '664442', '519588', '418812', '536532', '755570', '283832', '92004', '66890', '724520', '11594', '134742', '542684', '169910', '37022', '689762', '633878', '640968', '277550', '839162', '953150', '742370', '219954', '271058', '846722', '22398', '237930', '637712', '46220', '868740', '9872', '573108', '399720', '114810', '262194', '122100', '104712', '494354', '791804', '279110', '484544', '89460', '797682', '875298', '740522', '218510', '188954', '337794', '375158', '296160', '172604', '871958', '451362', '746414', '757344', '657894', '60734', '485732', '213650', '206300', '716858', '101064', '118820', '185750', '332264', '93288', '363590', '555828', '120284', '814008', '954912', '513698', '795002', '384344', '116960', '866738', '926660', '998528', '170384', '569244', '695504', '77864', '469070', '38784', '47388', '358484', '533738', '966432', '126714', '440822', '964040', '808958', '698388', '157428', '338412', '332208', '976514', '25794', '251540', '399872', '765468', '331142', '454722', '263958', '51614', '694080', '422268', '14754', '661268', '479798', '647402', '198842', '896112', '346562', '72354', '106950', '516234', '313154', '60728', '244640', '345732', '215768', '75980', '349110', '589140', '950690', '476888', '246540', '150908', '291104', '42768', '82470', '751278', '366678', '806904', '741080', '356094', '206828', '850388', '270338', '649218', '10274', '48884', '935814', '978750', '892628', '212678', '163212', '133650', '883974', '665294', '806762', '876824', '8838', '697262', '403434', '114408', '382862', '351438', '969342', '79802', '645000', '113028', '349338', '354150', '384548', '20564', '465644', '721452', '607418', '575250', '940032', '463890', '579282', '862992', '847664', '896634', '828408', '847202', '443940', '879114', '418512', '997202', '690104', '770184', '594750', '851034', '447108', '640650', '271218', '990762', '493920', '594642', '852830', '191562', '794994', '117390', '672902', '978018', '59772', '842450', '153818', '139362', '712302', '437862', '263724', '201894', '575220', '481640', '242010', '466730', '997370', '128450', '174222', '109904', '455970', '564498', '534740', '340802', '358074', '796152', '97022', '630024', '221874', '950738', '730592', '907394', '566988', '580982', '155502', '425520', '908808', '199374', '491498', '50232', '107468', '857322', '728628', '477410', '430290', '643458', '642582', '612714', '705560', '834470', '775344', '55734', '782088', '13800', '432344', '146778', '518412', '450600', '163322', '854958', '30894', '872090', '855734', '304212', '535124', '68438', '734480', '532752', '547038', '366522', '424268', '644364', '152658', '17402', '932750', '465008', '807540', '670730', '205398', '988850', '779900', '231968', '746024', '678612', '319682', '357564', '521982', '363902', '487692', '880730', '340958', '807338', '540612', '38012', '21912', '657500', '836570', '647430', '884294', '470078', '875114', '266354', '721058', '853970', '265872', '795102', '788078', '451580', '169952', '997268', '147648', '185768', '286802', '408744', '459230', '33108', '490004', '27998', '123050', '153702', '151142', '543828', '18798', '498104', '459842', '895314', '119298', '787712', '197424', '918752', '82268', '443732', '839430', '134334', '570392', '16964', '537242', '149112', '500180', '531912', '556944', '942860', '892862', '518690', '330612', '904088', '746678', '310232', '876374', '345908', '889280', '619188', '808994', '658212', '248888', '135572', '55890', '741342', '512538', '55932', '251622', '12228', '687458', '48342', '310364', '345228', '436158', '72720', '634688', '179990', '527942', '939924', '68042', '902502', '295334', '9414', '203354', '758112', '134918', '661482', '948174', '476082', '75330', '94874', '825108', '78008', '833048', '647588', '951278', '857714', '970538', '248628', '141444', '477768', '464814', '514278', '53234', '866714', '455514', '188300', '90620', '206624', '259682', '13760', '77154', '272772', '58604', '358880', '522080', '914240', '644790', '1700', '381570', '955278', '429242', '713192', '745934', '961100', '480584', '352250', '658488', '929808', '224430', '52584', '915974', '147180', '953112', '585792', '212058', '915144', '953502', '756704', '800144', '143138', '96780', '303890', '557282', '999050', '680658', '446934', '304962', '211868', '308928', '42452', '578484', '853320', '671358', '780050', '196908', '983930', '950810', '65124', '489794', '391250', '708284', '351078', '34920', '116868', '397634', '19604', '867620', '547770', '746792', '503624', '245630', '62202', '222008', '207470', '674162', '136538', '130100', '452042', '384488', '432662', '280352', '570192', '905652', '529808', '33410', '482622', '992372', '28278', '196202', '170778', '874772', '80538', '450842', '532452', '164430', '411992', '456960', '32942', '934002', '565248', '973760', '469770', '280298', '21384', '807474', '254520', '235242', '633938', '873404', '687180', '305472', '377844', '110850', '289848', '969444', '812138', '558422', '334932', '630920', '276444', '483140', '951362', '720092', '286814', '503054', '727668', '587520', '307512', '448598', '332952', '7322', '721014', '869900', '278690', '169244', '763494', '358314', '438828', '23628', '241982', '672044', '499854', '4458', '191510', '814328', '728874', '948090', '327344', '957332', '116868', '879170', '442208', '113024', '11312', '446190', '847934', '792108', '307578', '60938', '987660', '26628', '996600', '21882', '580170', '877940', '633470', '388692', '7938', '543608', '806372', '544938', '819150', '439788', '393630', '126962', '662714', '595962', '759180', '76718', '731118', '514890', '125222', '384438', '645684', '268884', '608118', '537374', '500258', '90584', '27774', '195992', '872090', '923712', '24692', '600360', '571854', '863120', '718304', '29790', '107508', '717428', '52070', '609374', '208254', '1230', '92684', '51488', '986114', '798228', '951080', '944310', '582458', '182058', '41958', '488922', '101604', '302010', '459182', '912344', '868874', '1298', '166350', '531638', '219282', '99000', '689412', '809604', '60398', '814008', '211658', '357672', '26628', '874824', '520380', '38288', '105608', '581730', '978474', '972684', '4598', '92762', '2162', '630912', '225242', '663654', '145220', '517824', '999102', '414312', '211502', '833310', '541712', '379724', '902600', '277494', '607038', '329432', '757364', '784628', '25170', '282428', '35324', '932664', '455402', '796260', '540588', '606302', '22434', '128340', '10464', '138684', '34614', '534342', '660120', '271068', '346440', '959370', '178118', '256020', '10772', '657708', '781044', '228678', '311882', '488', '510452', '327444', '875712', '647964', '869438', '121260', '579504', '532920', '938342', '540438', '784548', '260922', '186480', '653820', '163772', '130364', '959490', '810194', '812250', '375252', '168458', '476478', '838694', '257372', '311420', '615068', '961118', '950634', '702018', '408804', '111494', '591752', '467472', '599742', '374118', '509222', '283008', '91250', '362852', '718974', '580734', '755318', '920790', '908582', '72224', '936054', '698670', '892604', '510332', '171618', '688680', '299018', '864290', '426998', '663410', '710372', '521642', '43952', '389798', '753984', '107310', '81902', '915380', '883490', '275912', '70452', '702102', '170958', '479570', '269210', '871160', '158792', '473288', '345432', '758930', '848850', '725910', '557694', '515598', '30638', '571370', '189068', '294704', '793548', '745118', '832478', '615722', '156362', '854364', '688160', '363152', '631938', '236682', '460464', '36068', '269982', '634344', '348210', '249974', '324774', '705534', '79394', '122850', '694082', '346878', '704688', '880514', '77558', '647790', '39954', '635354', '407948', '3080', '131448', '365760', '533672', '923948', '657072', '565668', '324294', '105692', '762780', '342972', '591090', '752994', '815520', '216732', '99714', '114278', '480072', '632994', '684978', '666770', '997740', '820578', '293640', '411194', '446294', '550490', '933968', '443868', '13298', '214010', '46818', '182060', '383694', '955608', '515612', '717884', '1302', '739494', '572834', '264464', '947652', '565464', '496748', '574160', '651462', '186708', '957212', '464910', '638568', '22470', '238748', '830888', '239964', '94350', '830580', '561104', '403788', '28352', '433370', '943752', '160982', '262338', '641262', '404558', '720060', '171264', '972330', '380198', '351402', '287150', '633474', '338390', '33354', '534404', '169322', '372060', '692730', '52364', '652358', '74204', '419088', '499524', '513158', '648342', '718358', '294564', '335610', '8630', '652658', '408624', '339762', '786420', '73304', '379188', '527348', '148914', '430752', '644198', '200088', '957098', '340284', '278414', '162692', '883878', '335528', '694368', '192818', '96908', '754968', '222008', '653622', '552710', '721208', '300234', '592854', '382650', '336042', '445878', '148868', '217970', '489990', '9030', '443604', '829988', '224712', '187508', '1784', '735422', '600338', '52164', '182142', '582794', '412950', '447678', '869070', '597270', '172002', '625410', '894404', '769620', '53820', '103484', '852990', '332804', '895320', '361512', '331502', '187928', '771218', '66702', '580530', '725808', '530262', '828524', '814644', '877404', '621740', '592484', '442754', '791952', '186552', '9750', '50924', '742608', '794594', '241454', '379178', '177044', '43332', '702828', '426744', '302928', '349914', '656600', '311982', '254700', '376758', '85782', '893220', '337284', '308142', '443040', '615314', '95084', '893568', '127740', '306030', '390782', '90002', '286290', '155664', '723960', '650564', '64680', '482124', '700362', '806858', '217082', '672884', '173714', '489102', '174458', '432054', '241952', '240422', '439800', '611484', '937502', '286928', '371360', '473504', '961134', '10134', '412538', '456350', '945962', '673550', '862418', '426198', '809424', '152810', '931878', '698978', '243840', '473378', '630102', '665222', '351932', '538598', '819812', '53454', '526652', '91944', '473328', '505694', '93494', '511898', '996884', '100610', '787808', '946460', '589328', '317732', '617768', '730188', '554532', '309108', '818430', '170810', '316214', '17342', '855620', '933422', '987798', '939452', '42900', '185492', '970878', '403688', '2544', '157890', '269210', '536672', '9042', '305862', '615188', '143528', '867734', '16128', '182', '210462', '540804', '504390', '880872', '73422', '20232', '606380', '668154', '66404', '507140', '121622', '950334', '157680', '170844', '514562', '110588', '239384', '390114', '733374', '6222', '400754', '746414', '106020', '675974', '325518', '389570', '377790', '800874', '831168', '21408', '612612', '599244', '729614', '486768', '365852', '588738', '897008', '983318', '728994', '71414', '352742', '960738', '220404', '754302', '95604', '581558', '85082', '602040', '473444', '907470', '608498', '26634', '434510', '358230', '327402', '713564', '421350', '528392', '647838', '855672', '717668', '182048', '293484', '179820', '117530', '143528', '754532', '399044', '649262', '895244', '582018', '25764', '655718', '918890', '879798', '511172', '154098', '92204', '897882', '120504', '2790', '1500', '285674', '24152', '196728', '192588', '705644', '779082', '876722', '549644', '532404', '761928', '998540', '311792', '66960', '77478', '191232', '181838', '146678', '549944', '315698', '250920', '576882', '955334', '318824', '620492', '29412', '193608', '16092', '95582', '405818', '765104', '975900', '20850', '474788', '934598', '725520', '683358', '988902', '900624', '728948', '181362', '690120', '155382', '450422', '292460', '60590', '1784', '210128', '952670', '966212', '212124', '313344', '267498', '522000', '510050', '623478', '309092', '133968', '739202', '400314', '866400', '226484', '7220', '692250', '462444', '443190', '846578', '458070', '432924', '304430', '915642', '940760', '402342', '463680', '932022', '508302', '989798', '74288', '360008', '138060', '257540', '80898', '555684', '12792', '678578', '147254', '59264', '16488', '171518', '275340', '5642', '446262', '509522', '279680', '750312', '496314', '193800', '938808', '693878']
```

I can't copy all the 200,000 integers

Comment: All prime number greater than 3 are of the form 6n±1.  You can use that to limit the number of possible additions you test.  You will also find the Sieve of Eratosthenes useful.

Comment: @rossum that's what i have used it in the `isPrime()` function but still i get the timelimit exceed

Comment: I was thinking more about the numbers you add to the starting number to get a prime.  You should replace `isPrime()` with a lookup in a precaclulated Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: @rossum so you are saying to have a list full of prime numbers and check each added integer to it?

Comment: Yes.  Sieve all numbers up to 200,000 or whatever the upper limit for your problem is.  Then testing just becomes a lookup.

Comment: @rossum when you sieve prime numbers up to 100,000 it takes 3.99 sec to finish which means it does exceeds the time limit

Comment: That is very slow for a sieve.  Check your code against an [online example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Pseudocode); if you are doing any divisions then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @rossum my code matches that example but is still too slow... any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have to write it in Python? Even Python 3 is sensibly slower than C/C++, and that program can easily be converted to C.

Comment: 100ms limit for 100k numbers, that's short! Is there a "space" limit, how much memory can you use?

Comment: @e2-e4 thank you giving me such a great idea , i just did the same code in c++ and it ran successfully !

Comment: @e2-e4 There is no limit for space

Comment: It seems a bit unfair that the same time limit should be applied to interpreted code as applied to compiled code...

Comment: 100ms for each check or all 200,000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible solution. It generates a list of primes up to the maximum value of the input numbers, then uses a binary search to find the next largest prime relative to each input number, finally computing the difference between those values and the inputs:

```
from math import sqrt

def sieve(prime, n, primes):
    for i in range(prime*prime, n+1, prime):
        primes[i] = False
    return primes

def listPrimes(n):
    n = n * 2    # to allow for the largest input value not being prime
    primes = [False, False] + [True] * (n - 1)
    primes = sieve(2, n, primes)
    q = int(sqrt(n))
    for p in range(3, q+1, 2):
        if primes[p]:
            primes = sieve(p, n, primes)
    return [p for p in range(n+1) if primes[p]]

def findNextPrime(n, primes):
    i = len(primes) // 2
    if primes[i] >= n:
        if i == 0 or primes[i-1] < n:
            return primes[i]
        return findNextPrime(n, primes[:i])
    return findNextPrime(n, primes[i:])

nums = [89, 54, 91, 74, 44, 19, 12]
primes = listPrimes(max(nums))
nextPrimes = [findNextPrime(n, primes) for n in nums]
delta = [np - p for p, np in zip(nums, nextPrimes)]
print(delta)
```

Output:

```
[0, 5, 1, 5, 3, 0, 1]
```

**Update**

As @PresidentJamesK.Polk points out in the comments, this can be made more efficient by pre-computing the differences between each number and the next prime. This can be done by not filtering the sieve and then traversing it in reverse order to compute the distance from each number to the next prime:

```
from math import sqrt

def sieve(prime, n, primes):
    for i in range(prime*prime, n+1, prime):
        primes[i] = False
    return primes

def listPrimes(n):
    n = n * 2    # to allow for the largest input value not being prime
    primes = [False, False] + [True] * (n - 1)
    primes = sieve(2, n, primes)
    q = int(sqrt(n))
    for p in range(3, q+1, 2):
        if primes[p]:
            primes = sieve(p, n, primes)
    return primes

def primeDiffs(primes):
    primediffs = []
    i = len(primes) - 1
    while not primes[i]:
        i -= 1
    for i in range(i, -1, -1):
        if primes[i]:
            dist = 0
        else:
            dist += 1
        primediffs.append(dist)
    return primediffs[::-1]


nums = [89, 54, 36, 74, 44, 19, 12]
primes = listPrimes(max(nums))
diffs = primeDiffs(primes)
delta = [diffs[n] for n in nums]
print(delta)
```

Output:

```
[0, 5, 1, 5, 3, 0, 1]
```

**Note**

For both cases, `max(nums)` should be computed as the numbers are input to save time.

Comment: But it still exceeds the time limit, exceeds when the list nums has 100,000 values and each value of the list above 10^5

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, and thank you for your effort on my question

Comment: It would safe much time to also precompute the table prime_diff[i] = the difference between i and the next prime.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk that's an excellent idea I've updated the answer with code that works that way.

Comment: @DaVinci see the updated answer, it has a more efficient way of computing the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way of doing it, it's faster than 100ms for each item but slower for the full set ( even sieving takes longer than 100ms, and that's a fast algorithm):

```
from sympy import isprime
import random
import numpy as np

def primes_sieve2(limit):
    a = [True] * limit
    a[0] = a[1] = False

    for (i, isprime) in enumerate(a):
        if isprime:
            yield i
            for n in range(i*i, limit, i):
                a[n] = False

PRIMES=np.array(list(primes_sieve2(2750160)), 'uint32')

def create_random_array(limit=len(PRIMES)):
  vv = np.zeros(len(PRIMES), 'uint32')
  for x in range(limit-1):
     vv[x] = random.randint(0,pow(10,6))
  return vv

vv = create_random_array()
vvx = np.zeros(len(PRIMES), 'uint32')
count = 0
for xx in vv:
    vvx[count] = PRIMES[np.argmax(PRIMES > xx)] - xx
    count+=1

vvisprime = np.zeros(len(PRIMES), 'bool')
for x in range(len(PRIMES)):
   vvisprime[x] = isprime(int(vvx[x]) + int(vv[x]))



In [49]: vvx                                                                                                                                                   
Out[49]: array([ 5, 10, 13, ..., 12,  2,  2], dtype=uint32)

In [48]: vvisprime                                                                                                                                             
Out[48]: array([ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: Yup, This works but it's better not to use external libraries like `numpy` and `sympy`, @Nick 's answer does the work without exceeding limit and without any external libraries.Thank You for your efforts .